# How to use JvisualVM to profile Spark on Yarn cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, jvm, profiling

I know how to do this work on single executor host, just export JMX port.
But some potential performance issue only can be happened in large cluster, if we add JMX options to "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions", listen address of multiple executors on a host will conflict.

I also tried to start a jstatd daemon, but the visualvm can't do cpu profiling in this way(it has message on UI).

Is there way to profiling Spark application in large scale cluster especially pinpoint what does each thread do in some time and cpu cost profiling? Not considering commercial tools.

Comment: by any chance did you get this working? I am looking for something similar